# Navigating and submitting form properties

Tags: react-native

I am trying to navigate away from a screen and submit info with a handleSubmit.

```
export default class CreditRegister extends Component  {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const navigation = navigate(this.handleSubmit) 
    const value = this._form.getValue();
    console.log('value: ', value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
```

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeAddress')}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your **handlesubmit** fnc into your **Homeaddress** screen then you can pass the callback function like this.

```
export default class CreditRegister extends Component  {
      handleSubmit = () => {
       // your code
      }
      
      render() {
        return (
          <>
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeAddress',{handleSubmit:this.handleSubmit})}
          <>
```

then in your **HomeAddress** screen do it like this

```
export default class HomeAddress extends Component  {
          render() {

      const {handleSubmit}=this.props.route.params

            return (
              <>
              onPress={handleSubmit}
              <>
```